# JavaScript Regex Pattern that contains parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex, less

Using JavaScript I need to check a string for the first instance of a given pattern and return everything after, and including, the pattern. See example below for a typical string, pattern and desired result.

The main problem I am having is that the pattern will almost certainly contain special characters such as parentheses. I cannot alter the pattern manually to escape those special characters. Unless I am able to do that using `replace` first?

e.g. `result = string.match(pattern.replace`(special with escaped))

I'm not sure if anything like that is even possible. Regex always gives me a headache and I would appreciate any pointers in the right, or alternative, direction.

**Background**

I am trying to do some complex mixins for LESS. So I am restricted to single line JavaScript by escaping with the back-tick. See [here](http://lesscss.org/#-javascript-evaluation) for information regarding using JavaSCript in LESS. I was hoping to use the new variadic argument support to get multiple color-stops. e.g. .`radial-gradient(@shape, @position, @colorStops...)` However LESS only gives you the full range of arguments passed when you use @arguments. So I am hoping to use regex to use @arguments for the string and @colorStop for the pattern and return everything after, and including, the first color-stop. LESS returns the first color-stop variable when using @colorStop. The general concept was taken from [here](http://www.toekneestuck.com/blog/2012/05/15/less-css-arguments-variable/))

**For Example:**

> String: circle 0% 50% rgba(96, 16, 48, 0) 9px #661133 10px rgba(96,
>   16, 48, 0) 11px
>
> Pattern: rgba(96, 16, 48, 0) 9px
>
> Result: rgba(96, 16, 48, 0) 9px #661133 10px rgba(96, 16, 48, 0) 11px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"I cannot alter the pattern manually to escape those special characters. Unless I am able to do that using .replace first?"*

Yes you can. Given a variable `pattern` that is a *string* containing your regex pattern, then:

```
pattern = pattern.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
```

...will escape all of the characters that have special meaning in a regex, and put the result back in the same variable. Of course that only works if every character in your pattern is to be taken as a literal character to match.

> *"I need to check a string for the first instance of a given pattern and return everything after, and including, the pattern"*

I'd simply append `.*` to the end of the pattern, so then it will match the specified bit followed by all of the following characters. That is, if a regex `/abc/` matches the first instance of `"abc"` then the regex `/abc.*/` will match `"abc"` plus every character following. (In a regex, `.` matches any character, and `*` matches the previous bit zero or more times, by default doing a "greedy" match.)

Putting this together:

```
function matchToEnd(pattern, str) {
    var re = new RegExp(pattern.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + ".*"),
        result = str.match(re);
    if (result)
       return result[0];
    else {
       // didn't match, return default value of your choice, e.g.:
       return null;
    }
}

var result = matchToEnd("rgba(96, 16, 48, 0) 9px",
                        "rgba(96, 16, 48, 0) 9px #661133 10px rgba(96, 16, 48, 0) 11px");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JVdnz/

Note though that going back to the assumption I had to make earlier that your regex pattern didn't contain any characters that have special meaning in a regex, if that is the case then you don't need regex to do this task, you can just use the [`.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) in combination with the [`.substr()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
var i = str.indexOf(pattern);  // find index of first instance of pattern
if (i != -1)
   return str.substr(i);       // return from that index to end of string
```

Here's a demo similar to previous demo but with `.indexOf()` instead of regex: http://jsfiddle.net/JVdnz/1/

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response and the examples via jsfiddle. Both options look promising. I'm currently trying to adapt it to work within the limitations of the LESS compiler. Almost there :) I'll mark it as the correct answer as soon as I do get it working within LESS.

Answer (score 2):

If your pattern doesn not need to use any regex features, and if you only need to replace the first occurrance if it, then you can just pass a string as the pattern to the replace method.

Otherwise (if you need regex features or need to replace all occurences of the pattern) then you can [create a function to escape the special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript/3561711#3561711) in your string and dynamically generate a regex object.

Comment: I actually need to return everything after, and including, the pattern being matched. So I'm not sure how passing the pattern as a string to the replace method can help me achieve that. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding?

PS: Checking out the link you provided.